# How to perform this simple calculation in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sequence, tkinter-entry

(What's wrong with this code? 
There are two entry fields. I want to input grades either A or B and convert it into score then multiply the score with hours to get the final result.

If grade=A+ and hours =4 the answer should be 16. How to achieve this?)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Simple Calculatoion")


grade =Entry(root).pack()

hours= Entry(root).pack()


def calculation():

    global score

    if grade.get()=="A+":
        score=4

    elif grade.get()== "A":
        score = 3.7

    label=Label(root, text= score * hours.get() )
    label.pack()

button = Button(root, command=calculation, text="Calculate")
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***What's wrong with this code?***: Attempt to do math with string: `score * hours.get()`

Answer (score 2):

Consider that `hours.get()` will return a string, not a number.

Multiplying a string with a number usually doesn't work.

```
>>> 3.7*'4'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

And in case it does work, it doesn't do what you want:

```
>>> 3*'4'
'444'
```

Try this instead;

```
def calculation():
    scores = {'A+': 4, 'A': 3.7}
    score = scores.get(grade.get(), 1)
    try:
        num = float(hours.get())
    except ValueError:  # not a valid float
        num = 0
    # Create the label when you create the other widgets!
    # Just set the contents here.
    label['text'] = str(score * num)
```

The `scores` dictionary can easily be extended for other grades.

Note that I'm using the `get` method of a dictionary here because it handles the situation when the key isn't present in the dictionary. Observe:

```
>>> scores = {'A+': 4, 'A': 3.7}
>>> scores['A']
3.7
>>> scores['V']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'V'
>>> scores.get('V', 42)
42
```

Comment: That's a great help. The code is working now using dictionary. Thank you.